# Match a word with optional delimiters with sed, grep and PCRE

Tags: grep, sed

How do I match a word with optional delimiters?

Say I have a file named `file`

```
a
b
"a"
"a
c
```

and I want to match only quoted or unquoted `a` (I don't want to match `"a`). I'd like to do such match with `grep`, `sed` and Perl compatible regex. I could do

- `egrep '^("a"|a)$' <file` and
- `sed -nr 's/^("a"|a)$/\1/p' <file`

but it's... ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
egrep '^("?)a\1$' <file
```

See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730946/matching-in-matching-space-with-sed-since-when-it-is-supported/31731446

Comment: I expected some PCRE magic but this is indeed the simple trick I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

In Perl (one liner):

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if (m/^(a|"a")$/);' < filename
```

`$1` is the text captured in *inside* parentheses.

Output:

```
a
"a"
```

As a script you can write like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", "abc.txt" or die $!;

while (<$fh>)
{
    chomp;
    print $_, "\n", if (m/^(a|"a")$/);
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: That's just what I wrote rewritten to Perl.